# indexed sequential access method of a FILE in C

Tags: c, file, sorting

I need to organize the elements of a file in C with a indexed sequential access method but I have some trouble with an If() condition, when the new element of the FILE is either the "first", in the "middle" or the "last"one of my FILE, the elements are organized first by the category then by the brand and then by the name.

I understand the problem and I know where it is but I don't know how to write the if statement. The if condition in the code below is marked with "///->Here is the error<-"

OS is Win 10 and the IDE I'm using is Codeblocks

```
/** INPUT: FILE pointer, pprod is the new element to be organized in the file, PTO receives the number of the first element in the organized file   **/
/** PROCESS: Organize a FILE by the category, then by the brand(marque), then by the name of the product                                            **/
/** OUTPUT: /                                                                                                                                       **/

void fSequentielleLogique(FILE *Fproduit, struct fSequentielleFiche *pprod, int *PTO)   ///The fonction is called after the element is written into the file
{
    struct fSequentielleFiche TmpPrec, Tmp;
    ///The last element of the FILE receives -1
    pprod -> Offset = -1;
    ///When the FILE is just created PTO = -1
    if(*PTO == -1)
    {
        ///PTO receives the number (0) of the first element in the FILE
        *PTO = pprod -> Adresse;
        rewind(Fproduit);
        fwrite(pprod, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);
    }
    else
    {
        fseek(Fproduit, *PTO * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
        fread(&TmpPrec, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);
        TmpPrec.Offset = -1;

        fseek(Fproduit, *PTO * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
        fread(&Tmp, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);

        ///The elements are organized by the category
        while(Tmp.Offset != -1 && strcmp(pprod -> valeur.categorie, Tmp.valeur.categorie) > 0)
        {
            fseek(Fproduit, Tmp.Adresse * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
            fread(&TmpPrec, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);

            fseek(Fproduit, Tmp.Offset * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
            fread(&Tmp, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);
        }
        if(strcmp(pprod -> valeur.categorie, Tmp.valeur.categorie) == 0)
        {
            ///Then they are organized by the brand(marque)
            while(Tmp.Offset != -1 && (strcmp(pprod -> valeur.categorie, Tmp.valeur.categorie) == 0) && (strcmp(pprod -> valeur.marque, Tmp.valeur.marque) > 0))
            {
                fseek(Fproduit, Tmp.Adresse * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
                fread(&TmpPrec, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);

                fseek(Fproduit, Tmp.Offset * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
                fread(&Tmp, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);
            }
            if((strcmp(pprod -> valeur.categorie, Tmp.valeur.categorie) == 0) && (strcmp(pprod -> valeur.marque, Tmp.valeur.marque) == 0))
            {
                ///Then they are organized by the name
                while(Tmp.Offset != -1 && (strcmp(pprod -> valeur.categorie, Tmp.valeur.categorie) == 0) && (strcmp(pprod -> valeur.marque, Tmp.valeur.marque) == 0) && (strcmp(pprod -> valeur.nomProduit, Tmp.valeur.nomProduit) > 0))
                {
                    fseek(Fproduit, Tmp.Adresse * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
                    fread(&TmpPrec, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);

                    fseek(Fproduit, Tmp.Offset * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
                    fread(&Tmp, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);
                }
            }
        }
        if((strcmp(pprod -> valeur.categorie, Tmp.valeur.categorie) < 0) || (strcmp(pprod -> valeur.marque, Tmp.valeur.marque) < 0) || strcmp(pprod -> valeur.nomProduit, Tmp.valeur.nomProduit) < 0 || Tmp.Offset != -1) ///->Here is the error<-
        {
            //If I don't enter any loop I know that the element is the first of my FILE
            if(TmpPrec.Offset == -1)
            {
                fseek(Fproduit, pprod -> Adresse * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
                pprod -> Offset = *PTO;
                *PTO = pprod -> Adresse;
                fwrite(pprod, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);
            }
            ///The element is located in the middle of the FILE
            else
            {
                fseek(Fproduit, TmpPrec.Adresse * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
                fread(&TmpPrec, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);
                TmpPrec.Offset = pprod -> Adresse;
                fseek(Fproduit, TmpPrec.Adresse * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(&TmpPrec, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);

                fseek(Fproduit, pprod -> Adresse * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
                fread(pprod, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);
                pprod -> Offset = Tmp.Adresse;
                fseek(Fproduit, pprod -> Adresse * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(pprod, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);
            }
        }
        ///The element is the last one of the FILE and receives "-1"
        else
        {
            fseek(Fproduit, Tmp.Adresse * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
            fread(&Tmp, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);
            Tmp.Offset = pprod -> Adresse;
            fseek(Fproduit, Tmp.Adresse * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&Tmp, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);

            fseek(Fproduit, pprod -> Adresse * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
            fread(pprod, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);
            pprod -> Offset = -1;
            fseek(Fproduit, pprod -> Adresse * sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(pprod, sizeof(struct fSequentielleFiche), 1, Fproduit);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: [DRY] 1) you can reduce your code size by combining {fseek+fread} and {{fseek+fwrite} 2) Use a compare function.

Comment: Thank you I have written a compare function and it works fine now I was always looking for a quicker way (compare function is big) but this works fine.